# Install nvm in Dockerfile when container is built by Openshift fails with: returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: node.js, docker, openshift, nvm

I need to build a container with both Java and NodeJS 12. The following Dockerfile **works fine locally**:

```
FROM fabric8/java-centos-openjdk11-jdk:1.6.5
RUN echo "Base JDK11"

USER root

RUN curl -k -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
RUN source $HOME/.bashrc && nvm install 12.14.1

RUN ln -s $HOME/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.1/bin/node /usr/bin/node
RUN ln -s $HOME/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.1/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm

RUN node -v
RUN npm -v
```

However the actual container is built in Openshift which, for the very same Dockerfile, fails with `returned a non-zero code: 1`:

```
Step 9/15 : RUN source $HOME/.bashrc && nvm install 12.14.1
---> Running in 951805b39667

Removing intermediate container 951805b39667
error: build error: The command '/bin/sh -c source $HOME/.bashrc && nvm install 12.14.1' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: How does you build the container in openshift using the dockerfile?
First, in Openshift it's not allowed to do privileged work. Every run gets an artifical UID applied.
Aproach we use is the S2I System from Redhat, where we build the base image localy and let openshift use this image to merge code and image into a deployable image.
All privileged tasks are done localy, only copying and configuration of the application is done in open shift.

Comment: `source` isn't a standard Bourne shell command and it will fail on Alpine-based images.  You don't need a version manager like `nvm` for Docker images since it will only have a single version of Node at a time, so just install the single version you need (or, if you don't have strong version dependencies, the version your base OS has already packaged).